Can not use account after allocate the space
i'm new to solana. When i do allocate 100 byte from the docs on my account like this:
  let allocateTransaction = new Transaction({
    feePayer: senderKeypair.publicKey,
  });
  allocateTransaction.add(
    SystemProgram.allocate({
      accountPubkey: senderKeypair.publicKey,
      space: 0,
    })
  );
  const tx = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, allocateTransaction, [
    senderKeypair,
  ]);

i can't not use my account to send sol to other account. Why this happen, how to fix this and where is the docs for me to read more about this. Thanks for your time

Account Type Change: When you allocate space on an account using SystemProgram.allocate, it changes the account's type from a system account (which can hold SOL and send transactions) to a program data account (which is used to store data for programs)
Do Not Allocate on a Wallet Account: Typically, you should avoid using your main wallet account (i.e., the account with which you intend to send or receive SOL) to allocate space for program data. Instead, create a new account specifically for the data storage purposes
const newAccount = new Keypair(); // Create a new account
let allocateTransaction = new Transaction({
    feePayer: senderKeypair.publicKey,
});
allocateTransaction.add(
  SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: senderKeypair.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: newAccount.publicKey,
    lamports: await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(100),
    space: 100,
    programId: SystemProgram.programId,
  })
);
 const tx = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
 connection,               
 allocateTransaction,
 [senderKeypair, newAccount]
);


This is mostly correct. You should avoid setting the owner as SystemProgram.programId, since the account will be useless in that case! Try setting the programId to some useful program that can actually write data
